# changing object keys acording to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i have an object and 2 arrays. i want to change `object` keys according to `arr2`, object keys and `arr1` values are identical while `arr1` and `arr2` placement of values in arrays are identical but not values themselves, while i don't want to ask how to solve it want to know how should i approach this problem, thank you for your time

```
    const object = {
        name1: "some value",
        name3: "some value",
        name2: "some value",
        etc...}
    const arr1 = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
    const arr2 = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"]
```

expected outcome

```
    const newObject = {
        Name1: "some value",
        Name3: "some value",
        Name2: "some value",
        etc...}
```

Comment: So, you want a new object where keys names present on `arr1` are mapped to keys names on `arr2` and the rest of the keys stays as they are?

Comment: i need a new object which has old object values but all keys are replaced by `arr2`, as `arr1` and `arr2` placement of values are where i need and `arr1` value names are identical to old object keys.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you are mapping them by positions in your `arr1` and `arr2`.
Just run a loop.

```js
 const oldObject = {
        name1: "some value",
        name3: "some value",
        name2: "some value",
};

const arr1 = ["name1", "name2", "name3"];
const arr2 = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"];

var newObj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
  newObj[arr2[i]] = oldObject[arr1[i]];
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use reduce:

```js
const object = {
  name1: "some value",
  name3: "some value",
  name2: "some value",
}
const arr1 = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
const arr2 = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"]

const newObj = arr1.reduce((acc, value, index) => {
   acc[arr2[index]] = object[value]
   return acc
}, {})

console.log(newObj)
```

Reduce will loop over the array 1, use the same index from the second array to assign the key, and compare the value from the first array against the key from the object, and then assign it to the new object.

If readability isn't an issue, you can write the reduce in one line:

```js
const object = {
  name1: "some value",
  name3: "some value",
  name2: "some value",
}
const arr1 = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
const arr2 = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"]

const newObj = arr1.reduce((a, v, i) => (a[arr2[i]] = object[v], a), {})

console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce()`

```js
const object = {
        name1: "some value",
        name3: "some value",
        name2: "some value"
}

const arr1 = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
const arr2 = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"]

const res = arr1.reduce((ac,a,i) => (ac[arr2[i]] = object[a],ac),{});
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this:

```
var output={};
arr1.forEach(function(el, index){
   output[arr2[index]] = object[el];
}, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to preserve keys names not present on `arr1` on the new object. Then you can first create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) between **old names** and **new names** (In case `ES6` is not an option for you, use an object here for the mapping). Then you can traverse the [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to generate the new object, where only the related keys names are mapped to new ones, and the rest are preserved.

```js
const obj = {
  name1: "some value 1",
  name3: "some value 2",
  name2: "some value 3",
  name4: "some value 4",
  name5: "some value 5"
}

const arr1 = ["name1", "name2", "name3"];
const arr2 = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"];

// Create a map between old names and new names.
let keysMap = new Map(arr1.map((key, idx) => [key, arr2[idx]]));

// Generate the new object, preserving non-mapped keys names.
let newObj = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k, v]) =>
{
    acc[keysMap.has(k) ? keysMap.get(k) : k] = v;
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(newObj);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can one line this via [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and then [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
  const object = {
    name1: "some value A",
    name3: "some value B",
    name2: "some value C"
  }
  const old = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
  const keys = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"]

let result = Object.fromEntries(old.map((x,i) => [keys[i], object[x]]))

console.log(result)
```